# what is time after salat become kaza

Tags: salat, salat-qada

I only know about fajr and zhur, that fajr is qada when there is light in the sky and zhur become qada when the golden hour starts but I want to know what are other times that other Salat time are qada. Here is uk, the sky is well lit even after sun has down, so does it mean until it is complete dark there is still time to pray?

Answer (score 1):

First a prayer becomes qada' once it was not prayed on time!

The only prayer with a narrow time gap is the sobh or fajr (fard) prayer performing (or starting or reaching at least the first ruku') it after sunrise is qada'.

Else the ruling is simple the end time of any other prayer is the beginning time of the next. So you can perform Dhuhr until a few minutes before the adhan of 'Asr, and so on. But delaying to perform a prayer without necessity or excuse is strongly discouraged.

For the prayer scholars have defined terms such as the time of choice (al-Waqt al-Ikhtiyari) -at the beginning of the prayer time- and the time of necessity (al-Waqt ad-Darori) which is at the end of the prayer time.

Practical hint: Try to pray your prayers at least 5-10 min before the time given for the following prayer in your prayer sheet to avoid having missed the time!
But the better choice in any case would be pray it on time in a mosque!

Comment: when you _Try to pray your prayers at least 5-10 min before the time given for the following prayer in your prayer sheet_ what do u mean? doesn't call to adhan happen when the prayer sheet say so?

Comment: @Nofel I mean avoid missing to pray on time as prayer sheets have a certain error tolerance and one may loose his wudu' or want to pray the related sunnah prayers too... so take enough time for your prayers.

Comment: Regarding Fajr, so in winters the adhan is around 6 but sunrise is at 8:25 am. From what I know if the sky has light or brightness a little bit, it mean it’s Kaza. So give what u said about it that until sunrise it’s still not Kaza. Meaning I can pray until sunrise I.e. 8:25 and even sky is bright?

Comment: @Nofel yes, if you completed the first raka'a before 8:25 it is still on time, but with less rewards depending on your circumstances. As it is recommended to pray as early as possible.

Comment: It is funny we wake up for work but can’t for fajr. I m struggling to wake up at fajr even though I put on alarm but can’t. 1. I am afraid of silence 2. Afraid of dark outside. May Allah take away the things that scares me.